# Webpack global variable from multiple files

Tags: javascript, webpack, global-variables

I'm trying to rewrite bunch of legacy JS files into module structure. I have obfuscated plugin which contains out of few files, which in turn work with single global variable. The order of execution of these files matters.

**Example:**

*file1.js*

```
var myModule = {someStuff};
```

*file2.js*

```
myModule.someProperty = someValue;
```

What i want to achieve is to import them all somehow and get this global variable myModule.
**Possible implementation:**

*myModule.js*

```
import myModule from "file1.js";
import myModule from "file2.js"; // ofc i know it does not work this way

export default class myProgramm {
    constructor(){
        myModule.run({options});
    }
}
```

What i tried so far is webpack provide plugin (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/), but it doesn't work with multiple files. Also  i tried to use provide-multiple-plugin (adopted to webpack 4) from this gist :https://gist.github.com/shellscape/a7461022503f019598be93a512a1901a. But it seems to include files in nearly random order, so it can happen that myModule is not defined, while *file2.js* is executed first.

Comment: You may avoid putting .js in your import.

Comment: This may have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988320/webpack-bundles-my-files-in-the-wrong-order-commonschunkplugin

Comment: I dont think that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988320/webpack-bundles-my-files-in-the-wrong-order-commonschunkplugin solves the problem as it does not provide a way to access global variable defined in these file1 and file2

Comment: @Matheus Silva no it is not exported in either file1.js or file2.js