# Bootstrap related Javascript files bundled in the wrong order by Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, phoenix-framework

(There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988320/webpack-bundles-my-files-in-the-wrong-order-commonschunkplugin). However, my Webpack configuration is significantly different, and now the [official documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming) doesn't seem to recommend using `script-loader`, so I thought there might be a different solution to this question.)

Phoenix framework 1.4.0 uses Webpack by default. I was able to successfully configure it up to now.

Bootstrap.js requires `jquery` and `popper.js` to be loaded before it to work. So I specified:

```
import css from '../css/app.scss';

// webpack automatically bundles all modules in your
// entry points. Those entry points can be configured
// in "webpack.config.js".
//
// Import dependencies
//
import 'phoenix_html';

import 'jquery';
import 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap';

// Import local files
//
// Local files can be imported directly using relative
// paths "./socket" or full ones "web/static/js/socket".

// import socket from "./socket"

import { startLesson } from './lesson/show.ts';
```

in my `app.js`

However, the generated `app.js` looks like this:

```
/***/ "../deps/phoenix_html/priv/static/phoenix_html.js":
/*!********************************************************!*\
  !*** ../deps/phoenix_html/priv/static/phoenix_html.js ***!
  \********************************************************/
...

/***/ "./css/app.scss":
/*!**********************!*\
  !*** ./css/app.scss ***!
  \**********************/
...

/***/ "./js/app.js":
/*!*******************!*\
  !*** ./js/app.js ***!
  \*******************/
...

/***/ "./js/lesson/show.ts":
/*!***************************!*\
  !*** ./js/lesson/show.ts ***!
  \***************************/
...

/***/ "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js":
/*!*****************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js ***!
  \*****************************************************/
...

/***/ "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js":
/*!********************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js ***!
  \********************************************/
...

/***/ "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/esm/popper.js":
/*!***************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/popper.js/dist/esm/popper.js ***!
  \***************************************************/
...

/***/ "./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js":
/*!***********************************!*\
  !*** (webpack)/buildin/global.js ***!
  \***********************************/
...
```

which apparently put the vendor JS files in alphabetical order and thus made `bootstrap.js` unusable.

Actually, the [official Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/) suggests that only writing `import 'bootstrap';` should be enough. However, that also resulted in `jquery` and `popper.js` being bundled after Bootstrap.js.

Also, I think the custom JS files, i.e. `./js/app.js` and `./js/lesson/show.ts` should be loaded after the dependencies are loaded?

How should I change the Webpack configuration so that the JS files are bundled in the correct order?

The current `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, options) => ({
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin({ cache: true, parallel: true, sourceMap: false }), new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})]
  },
  entry: './js/app.js',
  // entry: './js/app.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'ts-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'css')],
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '../css/app.css' }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: '../' }])
  ]
});
```

Comment: have you used providePlugin to allow popper and jquery to be in the global scope?

Comment: @PlayMa256 Should I do that? I thought it sufficed to just use `import` as indicated by the Bootstrap documentation. Actually I can invoke jquery but problems are occurring because of the order. Guess I'll try to set up `providePlugin` and see if it works. Wonder if it will have negative effects such as increasing bundle size though I guess it shouldn't.

Comment: No, it does not increase, just adds that as "global"

Comment: @PlayMa256 I tried to add `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      Popper: 'popper.js'
    }),` to `plugins` in Webpack config, but it didn't seem to have any effect... I can't even find `jQuery` and `Popper` in the browser window for some reason, only `$` is there. Seems that no code actually explicitly required them, so they aren't loaded by Webpack anyways?

Comment: probably, i hate working with jquery. its been 4  years i had used it.

Comment: @PlayMa256 Same. I just use plain JS wherever I can. Unfortunately Bootstrap is bundled with it. I'm trying to use Bootstrap modal and am getting the error as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757968/bootstrap-modal-is-not-a-function, so it seems that there's some problem with the loading order of JS files.

Comment: Try using react-bootstrap, is a jquery-less alternative