# Does the <script> tag order matter for webpack generated files?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Unlike earlier versions of Webpack it seems now that with **Webpack 4** my application seems to work no matter in which order I place the `<script>` tags inside the html page.

Is the order now entirely irrelevant or are there any limitations to consider?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988320/webpack-bundles-my-files-in-the-wrong-order-commonschunkplugin

Comment: @ThamaraiT that is outdated (the question and answers from your link relate to webpack 2)

Comment: @jantimon Webpack generates the build folder for you. index.html is a part of it with scripts tags. Why will you want to change the order of it?

Comment: @kushalvm I created the code which generates those `index.html` pages and got a question on the html-webpack-plugin repository which I moved to this stackoverflow question to get feedback on the actual limitations

Comment: @jantimon yeah was reading your issue on github.

Comment: So you generate multiple bundles with Webpack? Your configuration is not quite clear to me.

Comment: @jantimon Hi, this question had been posted quite long ago, but I ran into the same issue. It seems that the script generated by webpack, the execution order does not matter at all. But I cannot understand why. how can webpack's "recursive dependency graph strategy" describe this? can you please explain more about this a bit? For example, generated bundle of create-react-app's script can be executed without any error no matter in which order they are placed.

Answer (score 1):

If i get your question correctly, I don't think order of script tags should matter in `index.html` just because of the way webpack bundles the dependencies.

When webpack encounters any module it resolves the dependencies recursively. I mean all the require/import statements first. Say it's your entrypoint script. It creates a separate/single bundle for it ( including all it's dependencies) and spits it out as per the name specified under your output entry in config file and places this generated bundle.js/chunk.js a single entry inside index.html file.

For async module a separate chunk is generated and will not impact our order as it's clear that you don't need it to load it first and hence asynchronously loaded.

For vendor chunking too, order doesn't matters as these are independent modules.

Hope, it helps!