# Webpack: build app from multiple directories

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have following app tree:

- my_app

  - src

    - js

      - dir_1_with_js
      - ...
      - dir_n_with_js
      - package.json
      - webpack.config.js
      - script_1.js
      - ...
      - script_n.js
    - ui

      - ui_dir_1_with_js
      - ...
      - ui_dir_n_with_js
      - ui_script_1.js
      - ...
      - ui_script_n.js

For explanation: current application was developed using webpack and directory `js`. Now, I need to (slowly - page by page) transform current state into another one, so I would like to separate it. I have created directory `ui` in where I will develop new app UI. But this change unfortunately cannot be done as new and complete UI, but it will be transformed page by page, so I need to process both directories `ui` and `js` by one webpack.

I would like to call: `npm run webpack` from the directory `js` and I need that webpack will compile all scripts from the directories `js` and `ui`. Is it possible some way? What I should "say" to webpack? What configuration should be done in `webpack.config.js` to make it work?

I hope I've explained it well. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What does your current webpack.config.js look like? And what WP version are you using?

Comment: You should share your `webpack.config.js`. Based on what you wrote, you should have an `entry` object in config with 2 bundles, one for js and one for ui. Usually these bundles point to a main file *main.js*/*index.js* and those files imports/requires all the necessary stuff, webpack will load them if paths are accessible in dev/prod mode.

Comment: You are right, I am quite newbie to webpack. There are some entry points and it should not be any problem to pass path like '../ui/main.js'. Now I feel very foolish. Thank you @darklightcode, if you make an answer from your comment, I can mark it as a solution. New entry point for ui target, how simple is it.

Comment: @Honza you can check my answer and make sure to read the *important note!* at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change in `webpack.config.js` the [`entry`](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) property will point to your main files, after that, webpack will serve both of them :

**webpack.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './path/to/js/folder/app.js',
    ui: './path/to/ui/folder/ui.js',
  },
  output: {
    // [name] will output as the key of the entry point 
    // e.g. app.bundle.js and ui.bundle.js
    // webpack dev server will include them by default in html
    filename: '[name].bundle.js', 
  },
  ...
};
```

**app.js:**

```
console.log('main js logic')
```

**ui.js:**

```
console.log('extend logic');
```

**Important note!**

Sometimes the order of which the scripts that are loaded **matter**, if webpack outputs them in a order you don't like or doesn't work for you check out this topic for the issue itself:

[Webpack bundles my files in the wrong order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988320/webpack-bundles-my-files-in-the-wrong-order-commonschunkplugin)